# Conditional Probabilities - Are the Events Independent - Confused About part of this problem

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

No answers to refer to, so would be really greatful if someone can take a look at this problem and explain me a bit where am I going wrong or if I've done something right to begin with, haha.

A fair coin is tossed tree times. Specific the probability space for the experiment and consider the following events:
A: The result of the third toss is heads
B: the coin shows heads exactly two times

Compute the conditional probabilities P(A given B) and P(B given A). Are A and B independent?

So our sample space is: ${HHH}, {TTT}, {HHT}, {HTT}, {THH}, {TTH}, {HTH}, {THT}$

Hence, $P(A): 0.5$

$P(B): 0.375$

We can see that event A appears exactly 2 times when event B happens, hence, A is independent of B as the conditional probability of A given B is still equal to the probability of event A= 0.5

However, I'm a bit confused for the second part in finding the conditional probability of B given A. B is appearing also twice while A is taking place, but that is different than the probability of event B alone, so is it true that B is dependent on A? 0.66 versus the P(B) = 0.375. If so, how do we compute the conditional probability? Any help would be much much aprpeciated!

Comment: try drawing a venn diagram?

Comment: ops, my bad, thanks @lulu corrected

Comment: To your question:  Note that if the events are independent then the conditional probabilities must equal the ordinary probabilities.

Comment: Note: the following are equivalent statements  $A$ and $B$ are independent, $Pr(A\mid B)=Pr(A), Pr(B\mid A)=Pr(B), Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)Pr(B)$.  If a single one of those is true then they are all true.  If a single one of those are false then they are all false.  If your work implies that $Pr(A\mid B)=Pr(A)$ while simultaneously implying that $Pr(B\mid A)\neq Pr(B)$ then  you know that you have made a mistake as this is an impossible scenario.

Comment: In finding $Pr(A\mid B)$, note that there are exactly *three* equally likely outcomes where $B$ is true, and of those three outcomes, *two* of them $A$ is true as well.  You have $Pr(A\mid B)=\frac{2}{3}$ (*which I would point out is close to but /not/ the value 0.66*), not the $0.5$ that you say you found.

Comment: In writing my last comment, I think I see your problem... you may have mixed up the meanings of $Pr(A\mid B)$ and $Pr(B\mid A)$.  Remember that $Pr(A\mid B) = \dfrac{Pr(A\cap B)}{Pr(B)}$ which in the convenient setting where all outcomes in the sample space are equally likely simplifies nicely to $\dfrac{|A\cap B|}{|B|}$.  That is, when finding $Pr(A\mid B)$ you count how many times $B$ is true and *this* is the denominator for your fraction, not the number of times where $A$ is true.